# Case statement for calculating hours

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have the following formula to convert the duration into hours. I want to do case where any duration which is 15 min or more Is considered as an hour. for instance 1 hour 15 min will be calculated as 2 hrs, 2 hrs 15 min will be calculated as 3 hrs and so on. if it is less than 15 min after an hour than it will be the hour. eg 1 hr 5 min will be considered 1 hour.

((Case T0.DurType  when 'M' then (T0.Duration/100)/.60  when 'D' then (T0.Duration*8)  Else T0.Duration  End)) as 'Duration'

Comment: What does the `T0.Duration` column contain, I  mean milli-seconds, seconds or something else.

Comment: Duration is the calculated column. It displays the difference between start time and end time which are int. it is numeric.

Comment: But duration is measured in a time format like years, days, hours, seconds and so on, and all of them are ints.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to get an sql script working. Can you post sample data?

Comment: Give the sample data on how `TO.Duration` will contain. Then only it is possible to answer your query.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you doing this in SQL or as a formula field in Crystal?
2. Is `case` syntax required for some reason, or is that simply the approach you initially chose?
3. What unit of time does each increment of `Duration` represent, 1 second, 1 minute?

Assuming the following:

- this is in sql
- `case` syntax is not required
- each increment of `Duration` is 1 minute

Then here is your correct formula, using `ceiling` rather than `case`:

```
ceiling(T0.Duration/60) as "Duration"
```

That will increment any partial decimal value to the next highest integer, e.g., 75 minutes / 60 = 1.25  hours, and ceiling will increment to 2. 180 minutes / 60  = 3.00 hours and ceiling will output 3.

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure what you mean by achieving it in sql & crystal... if you calculate it in sql, it's passed to Crystal and won't need any further transformation. Either way, here's both solutions:

- Crystal: Assumes minutes are used. the "\" operator is integer division, so the decimal is dropped. A simple if/then/else `iif` is used to add either 1 or zero if the remainder minutes are 15 or more:
  `MINUTES \ 60 + IIF (MINUTES mod 60 >= 15,1 , 0)`
- In SQL (MySQL syntax, MSSQL/TSQL may vary) achieves the same as follows:

  `floor(MINUTES / 60) + IF( (MINUTES % 60) >= 15,1 , 0)`

Comment: I was using case because when we include the duration field in our query it displays minutes eg 15 min as 15 and one hour as 1 in management studio. In SAP it however displays it as 15 Minutes or 1 hour. I didn't know about ceiling as I don't have much knowledge of sql dev. However ceiling function would convert anything more than 1 hour to 2 hrs even if it is one min over. where as in my case it should only convert when it is 15 min over.

Comment: I want to achieve it in sql and in crystal.

Comment: I have replaced Minutes in the formula with column name duration and I am getting error.

Comment: You will need to provide more details. What is the error, exactly? Copy & paste it, or type it exactly. do not paraphrase or leave anything out. Also, provide a few samples of the raw data, what it looks like prior to formulas.